# Truncate beginning of label

Tags: cocoa, swift, nstextfield

I have a label (`NSTextField`) with text aligned right. When the text becomes too large to display, the end of the text is truncated (at the right edge of the label). In my case I would actually want to truncate the beginning of the text. How can I achieve this in the Interface Builder or in code?

**Now**

```
| This sentence is to |
```

**Desired**

```
| entence is too long |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this works for NSTextFields, I know it does for UILabels, but have you tried :

```
myTextField.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingHead
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is

```
[[myTextField cell] setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead];
```

Swift:

```
myTextField.cell.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingHead
```